# Perl script not running from ksh file

Tags: perl, ksh, sql-loader

I'm trying to run a bit of perl inside a ksh file and not getting what I would expect from it. Rather than simply getting some sort of error if I was doing something syntactically incorrect, it finishes running and creates lots of `.bak` files but has not prepended `$data` onto every line of the file as I would have expected.

What I've got so far (`contains` is a function I declared earlier in the file but that part works fine):

```
if [[ $# != 3 ]];then
     echo "Please specify 1 folder containing data files as well as 1 from and 1 to system id."
else
    for file in `ls $1`;do
        filePath=$1$file
        fileName=`echo $filePath | awk -F'/' '{print$5}'`
        contains $fileName "ACCUMS" && (
            contains $fileName ".bak" || (
                echo "Loading file: "$fileName  
                date=echo $fileName | awk -F'_' '{print$5}' | sed 's/.txt//'   
                data=$fileName"|"$2"|"$3"|"$date"|"  
                echo $data  
                echo /usr/local/bin/perl -pi.bak -e 's/^/$data/' $filePath  
                logFile="log"$curFile".txt"  
                echo "Log file: "$logFile  
                echo "Done loading file: "$fileName  
                $ORACLE_BIN/sqlldr user/pass@server control=control_file.ctl data=$filePath log=$logFile  
                curFile=$curFile+1
            )
        ) || echo $fileName" not part of Accums.  Skipped."
    done
fi
```

To make it worse when I run the following straight up in PuTTY it works, so it appears to be the way that I'm trying to call the perl code (even though I've looked a several examples doing similar things) from the `.ksh` file:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/^/hi|/' /path/data/file_Im_working_with.txt
```

If it matters, the log files are also not quite doing what I want.  Rather than making lots of them for each sqlldr call it just overwrites `log0.txt` every time.  I've checked, the data files are in the correct location and everything so this may be part of my problem or something completely unrelated.

Thanks in advance!

#### EDIT

In addition to what ThisSuitIsBlackNot and dms said, I also didn't need to specify the location of perl on this system and doing so was actually messing it up, which is weird because I checked and perl stuff was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dms pointed out, you are echoing the perl command, not executing it. Also, if you want the variable `data` to be interpolated, you need to use double quotes, not single quotes. Change this:

```
echo /usr/local/bin/perl -pi.bak -e 's/^/$data/' $filePath
```

to this:

```
/usr/local/bin/perl -pi.bak -e "s/^/$data/" $filePath
```

(the echo is not necessary to run the command)

Comment: hm, it's still not prepending $data even after removing the echo and switching to double quotes.  Is it possible that it doesn't like having the file be in a different directory?

Comment: @dlkulp `echo $filePath` immediately before this line and make sure the path you're providing is an actual file that you have write permissions to.

Comment: ah, looks like I also didn't need to specify the location of perl on this system, so it works now!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are `echo`ing the perl command but not actually running it.